# Detect device type & orientation to adjust view

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, orientation, device

I'm pretty certain I'm going about this in the completely wrong way now - but before I abandon ship & start again I thought I'd ask... I basically need to be able to detect the device that is using the app (iPhone 4 or iPhone 5) & the orientation the device is in & then adjust the output of my viewcontroller based on these - here is what I have:

To detect device (ok it doesn't detect device it's just if it's a bigger screen but thats OK for me!):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - (    double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Using the macro to detect device, along with code to detect orientation & then adjust view:

```
- (void)doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
    _Logo.frame = CGRectMake(97, 50, 127, 150);
    _timeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(17, 248, 286, 21);
    _years.frame = CGRectMake(70, 277, 35, 50);
    _yearsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(64, 335, 42, 21);
    _months.frame = CGRectMake(145, 277, 35, 50);
    _monthsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(131, 335, 58, 21);
    _days.frame = CGRectMake(220, 277, 35, 50);
    _daysLabel.frame = CGRectMake(216, 335, 39, 21);
    _hours.frame = CGRectMake(70, 393, 35, 50);
    _hoursLabel.frame = CGRectMake(62, 451, 46, 21);
    _minutes.frame = CGRectMake(145, 393, 35, 50);
    _minutesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(132, 451, 61, 21);
    _seconds.frame = CGRectMake(220, 393, 35, 50);
    _secondsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(203, 451, 68, 21);
} if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && IS_IPHONE_5) {
    _Logo.frame = CGRectMake(221, 20, 127, 150);
    _timeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(141, 178, 286, 21);
    _years.frame = CGRectMake(87, 221, 35, 50);
    _yearsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(83, 279, 42, 21);
    _months.frame = CGRectMake(162, 221, 35, 50);
    _monthsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, 279, 58, 21);
    _days.frame = CGRectMake(234, 221, 35, 50);
    _daysLabel.frame = CGRectMake(232, 279, 39, 21);
    _hours.frame = CGRectMake(308, 221, 35, 50);
    _hoursLabel.frame = CGRectMake(302, 279, 46, 21);
    _minutes.frame = CGRectMake(385, 221, 35, 50);
    _minutesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(372, 279, 61, 21);
    _seconds.frame = CGRectMake(466, 221, 35, 50);
    _secondsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(449, 279, 68, 21);
} else {
    _Logo.frame = CGRectMake(177, 20, 127, 150);
    _timeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(97, 178, 286, 21);
    _years.frame = CGRectMake(27, 221, 35, 50);
    _yearsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(23, 279, 42, 21);
    _months.frame = CGRectMake(102, 221, 35, 50);
    _monthsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(90, 279, 58, 21);
    _days.frame = CGRectMake(174, 221, 35, 50);
    _daysLabel.frame = CGRectMake(172, 279, 39, 21);
    _hours.frame = CGRectMake(248, 221, 35, 50);
    _hoursLabel.frame = CGRectMake(242, 279, 46, 21);
    _minutes.frame = CGRectMake(325, 221, 35, 50);
    _minutesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(312, 279, 61, 21);
    _seconds.frame = CGRectMake(406, 221, 35, 50);
    _secondsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(389, 279, 68, 21);
}
}
```

If I comment out the middle bit the app runs fine on the iPhone 5 simulator, but when I use the iPhone 4 simulator & rotate the device the labels go off the screen - this is my reason for needing to detect the device (its fine in portrait mode on both devices as the bottom set of labels dont go to the bottom of the screen).

If I run it as is - the labels & logo display in landscape view even if the device (any device) is in portrait mode/view.

I'm guessing the problem is some form of 'fall through' or logic error with my setup/plan but I cannot think of another way to word/program this at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the code in the else block to run only for 3.5 inches devices in landscape mode right?
In that case you need to add an else before the second if, otherwise the third block of code after the else statement will always run and if I understood correctly, it will create a landscape layout, regardless of the orientation you are passing in.

Comment: not quite - I need to run the bit of code in the 1st if-block if any device is in portrait mode, run the 2nd if-block if the device is an iPhone 5/widescreen device AND is in landscape mode, if it is not an iPhone 5/widescreen but is still in landscape mode I want the else-block of code to run (for a 3.5" screen) - hope that makes sense!

Comment: Then you need to change that else into an else if and check that the orientation is landscape, cause for the way you have currently implemented it, that else block will always run unless the device is an iPhone 5 and the orientation is landscape.

Comment: yes that sorted it thanks - also realised I need to create a new macro for non-widescreens (modified 568 points to 480) & add it as a condition to the outstanding if's as they were 'true' along with the I_PHONE_5 one!